# Can Apotomo render pass parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apotomo

I am using Apotomo with Rails and I have some code that looks like this:

```
root.find_widget(:messages).render :state => :display
```

which works fine.

I would like to pass some data along with that call. How do I do that?

I imagine something like this:

```
root.find_widget(:messages).render :state => :display, :my_variable => its_value
```

and then to be able to access `my_variable` in the widget's display method.

Please is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `render_state` that comes from *Cells*, upon which *Apotomo* is built. It can be used with arguments like this:

```
root.find_widget(:messages).render_state(:display, my_variable: its_value)
```